# Is there a way I can reuse a property defined in pom.xml, as Integer type in another *.xml file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, pom.xml, hazelcast

I am setting up hazelcast.xml file for my project. I have two profiles defined in pom.xml, and both needs to be on different . I declared a property in pom as  and within each profile I am setting it to be 1 (prof1) or 2 (profile2). In the hazelcast.xml when I try to access this variable using 3${myId}4, the IDE shows error since mulitcast-port is defined to be only "int" in the hazelcast-config-2.1.xsd

Since multicast-port is defined with restriction and base as "xs:int", the accessing ${myId} is failing being a string.

```
<!-- pom.xml -->

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>testProfile1</id>
            <properties>
                <myId>1</myId>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>testProfile2</id>
            <properties>
                <myId>2</myId>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

```
<!--hazelcast.xml-->

    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true">5701</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="true">
                <multicast-group>someGroup${myId}</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>3${myId}4</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="false">
                <member>localhost</member>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>
        <socket-interceptor enabled="false" />
    </network>
```

I am trying to get mulicast-port value to be set to 314 for profile1 and 324 for profile2

Tomcat Logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3${myId}4"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder.handleMulticast(XmlConfigBuilder.java:489)
    at com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder.handleJoin(XmlConfigBuilder.java:435)
    at com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder.handleNetwork(XmlConfigBuilder.java:266)
    at com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder.handleConfig(XmlConfigBuilder.java:188)
    at com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder.parse(XmlConfigBuilder.java:181)
    at com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder.build(XmlConfigBuilder.java:135)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast configuration variables are filled at the runtime, not at the compile time. You can have a look at the related [Hazelcast Using Variables documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.1/manual/html-single/index.html#using-variables).

So, in your case:

- if you use Maven just to compile your application, then you can't use Maven properties to fill hazelcast.xml variables
- if you use Maven also to run your application (`mvn exec`), then you add the argument `-DmyId=SOME_VALUE` to your `pom.xml`

Comment: Thanks Rafal, when I run `mvn pacakge`, classes in target directory should have actual values instead of placeholder. I forgot to include the hazelcast.xml for web-resources in plugin, doing this solved my problem.

Comment: No `mvn package` just compiles and packages, so the variables are not injected. They are injected when you run Hazelcast.

Answer (score 0):

In pom.xml, I forgot to include hazecast.xml file in order to use declared property

```html
<plugin>
  <configuration>
    <webResources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>webappDirectory</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>pathToHazelastFile</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </webResources>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```